# Find the area of the region between two lines and $ x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area

I need to know the area between $y = 2x+4$ and $y = 4x$. Between each other before they intercept at $(2, 8)$. That's against the $y$-axis.

this will help [image: i.imgur.com/mwprtCt.png]

Comment: The link currently does not work. If I am guessing right, the triangle has "base" going from $(0,0)$ to $(0,4)$, and has "height" $2$ with respect to that base. By the way, the intersection point is $(2,8)$.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/mwprtCt.png

Comment: I guessed right, which is surprising since my blood caffeine level is still low. Good picture!

Comment: unfortunately i am unable to correct my question, thank you to those who helped. greatness is not only in you but u must find what you love. if what you love is maths, by all means, pursue your dream.

Comment: @user246960  You can edit your question by clicking on the edit button at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 3):

if you take the $y$-intercept of $4$ as the base, then the height is the $x$-coordinate of $2$ of the point $(2,8).$  so the area of the yellow triangle is $$\frac 12 \times 4 \times 2 = 4$$

Comment: If we take the side that lies on the $y$-axis as the base, then the height is the $x$-coordinate of the point $(2, \color{red}{8})$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can get the area.

From the point of intersection, p$(2,8)$, drop a perpendicular on the Y-axis, giving 8 units as the result.

Base is 4 units. The length of the side, lying on the y axis.

Then, the area is given by

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\times 4 \times 8= 16$$

You can also use the Hero's formula. Because, you know all the coordinates of the triangle, and using them you can get the sides. Calculate the semi-perimeter

$$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$

and use below, to calculate the area

$$Area=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a rectangle with vertices $(0,0),(2,0),(8,0)$,and$(8,2)$. The rectangle, which has an area of $8*2=16$, is divided into three triangles, with the middle one being the area you're looking for. The 'top' triangle has a base of 4 and height of 2, so it's $0.5*4*2=4$. The 'bottom' triangle has a base of 2 and a height of 8, so its area is $0.5*8*2=8$. So the area of the triangle you're looking for is $16-8-4=4$.

Comment: I think you ought to check the point of intersection of the lines as Andre pointed out above..